# SwiftUI - State Bool Array not appending in init() function

Tags: arrays, swiftui, boolean, init

I'm attempting to use a for-loop to set the values of a Bool array in SwiftUI as follows:

```
@State var expanded: [Bool] = []

init() {
  for i in 0..<5 {
    expanded.append(false)
  }

  print(expanded)
}
```

However, the print statement only prints `[]`, and the array seems to be empty. Could anyone explain why the array is not being appended to and how I can fix this?

Comment: Of course, @Asperi's solution is correct. I'm assuming this question is representative of a more complex issue, but if not, and the scenario is as straightforward as the example, then the easiest solution is `@State var expanded: [Bool] = .init(repeating: false, count: 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with `State`, create and initialize instead, like

```
@State var expanded: [Bool]

init() {
  var values: [Bool] = []
  for i in 0..<5 {
    values.append(false)
  }

  print(values)
  _expanded = State(initialValue: values)    // << here !!
}
```

or better

```
@State var expanded: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: 5)
```